# Why is my knockoutjs computed observable not working?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I can't seem to have a computed value of this working. any input would be appreciated.

i get the values for my prices from server.

```js
 var pModel = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.prices = ko.observable({ "ID": 1,"Price1": 12,"Price2": 12});

     self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
         var total = 0;
         total = self.prices().Price1 + self.prices().Price2;
         return total;
     });
 };
 var VModel = new pModel();
 ko.applyBindings(VModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>Prices</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="calc">
            <tr>
                <td>Price 1</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: prices().Price1' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>price 2</td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: prices().Price2' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: $root.Total"></span>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `prices` variable is observable, but its members aren't. Redefine it like this:

```
 self.prices = ko.observable({
     ID: ko.observable(1),
     Price1: ko.observable(12),
     Price2: ko.observable(12)
 });
```

Now, this *almost* works, but if you change the values, it'll convert them to strings, so the total of `18` and `12` will be `1812`! We'll need to turn those strings into numbers.

```
 self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
     var price1 = parseFloat(self.prices().Price1());
     var price2 = parseFloat(self.prices().Price2());
     return price1 + price2;
 });
```

You should be all set!

Comment: I am getting this: self.prices = ko.observable({ "ID": 1,"Price1": 12,"Price2": 12}); from server .. how can I make them observable if so?

Comment: The [Knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You mixed things up a bit: Every value that other parts of your view model should be able to react on if changed must be an observable. In your case, you have an object "prices" which is an observable but the properties of this object (such as "Price1" and "Price2") are no observables. This means, that your computed observable would only be updated if the whole object placed in "prices" would be replaced by a new value.

So just make these values obserable:

```
var pModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.prices = {
        "ID": 1, // IDs normally do not change so no observable required here
        "Price1": ko.observable(12),
        "Price2": ko.observable(12)
    };

    self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
        return +self.prices.Price1() + +self.prices.Price2();
    });
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjgvx/3/

Comment: You'll want to `parseFloat` on the prices before you compute the total, otherwise they'll combine strings.

Comment: I am getting this: self.prices = ko.observable({ "ID": 1,"Price1": 12,"Price2": 12}); from server .. how can I make them observable if so?

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper Look into the mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: will look into that.. your response actually appends the total instead of actually adding it.